# Simulate >2 variables from Gumbel Copula

Tags: simulation, copula, gumbel-distribution

I'm trying to simulate multiple random variables with different taus from the Gumbel copula. For the normal copula it's pretty simple, eg:

```
library(copula)
myCop <- normalCopula(param=c(0.4,0.2,.3), dim = 3, dispstr = "un")
normtest = rCopula(1000, myCop)
```

But for the Gumbel copula, it seems to only want to do it is all the taus are the same. I tried:

```
library(gumbel)
alphas = c(1.5, 1.2, 2)
test = rgumbel(n = 1000, dim = 3, alpha = alphas)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you try to simulate a multivariate Gumbel copula. In multivariate non-elliptical copula, there is a restriction to the parameters. Only one parameter value needs to be fitted to the multivariate data. This is one main drawback for copula function. You need to look for nested copula function, however, it is really hard. So, you may need to use pair-copula construction. Therefore, you can fit Gumbel copula to your data very easily, look for `VineCopula` or `CDVine` copula packages in `R`.